# How can change the default authentication method in MariaDB / MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to set the default authentication method to `unix_socket`.

Following the instructions here:
https://lindevs.com/change-default-authentication-plugin-in-mysql/

I added to `my.cnf` :

```
[mysqld]    
default_authentication_plugin=unix_socket
```

And restarted: `sudo service mysql restart`

Unfortunately, I don't see any change:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'default_authentication_plugin';
Empty set (0.001 sec)
```

This is on WSL1 and 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1-log Debian 10.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`default_authentication_plugin` is a MySQL system server variable and not in [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/).

For the moment you'll need to specify the plugin explicitly when creating users.

There's no [feature requests](https://jira.mariadb.org/) to add this functionality yet.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-variable-differences-between-mariadb-102-and-mysql-57/.